# Is that possible to define hybrid_property in imperative mapping SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I use imperative mapping in SQLAlchemy to separate tables and domain models. Is that possible to define hybrid property, i.e. like that:

```
mapper_registry.map_imperatively(
Model,
model,
properties={
    "fullname": model.c.first_name + model.c.last_name,
},)
```

Comment: I haven't found a way to do this with a hybrid property. I've had to fall back on using a column_property instead. Very interested to see if anyone else knows about this, though.